# imagick stop working on server

Tags: php, apache, imagick

I have an application in php that creates some images with imagick.
It was working correctly but suddenly it stops working.
On my localhost it works correctly. But on server it stop working. Not showing any error and don't output anything.

But this only happens when I create a new Imagick with file.

ie:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(100, 100, new ImagickPixel('red'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

this works fine

but if I use an image:

```
$image = new Imagick('img.png');
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

this doesnt work.

I checked the phpini and the imagick is enabled, and the permissions are 777.

the tmp partition:

```
Filesystem    Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
tank/data     2.6T     99G    2.5T     4%    /
```

My questions is: What is wrong? And what could be changed for this stop working?
Can be the extension is broken?

Comment: `tmp` partition is full on your server.

Comment: no tmp is not full, see my edit

Comment: and you're `positive` that tmp is written to that partition?

Comment: not 100% positive. How can I check if where is the tmp partition?

Comment: `sys_get_temp_dir` should be pretty reliable

Comment: yes the tmp dir is exactly this on /tmp/ and its not full. I deleted everything thats inside